# 8000 AED is good offer to living in Dubai?

Tags: accommodation, cost-of-living, uae

I got an offer from a Dubai-based company with a salary of 8000 AED/Month + Annual Air ticket and basic benefits as UAE labor low.

Currently, I am working in UK base consulting firm in Mumbai and i am earning 75000 INR (Approx. 4139.93 AED)

I need to know what is the cost of living in Dubai? Is 8000 AED enough for me to survive in Dubai and send some money to my family in India also?

Below are my details:

- Willing to share accommodation
- Prepare my own food
- I can very much adapt to medium facilities
- I'm a bachelor now, maybe will marry after 1 years

Thanks

Comment: Very closely related: [Living expenses in Abu Dhabi, for a moderate lifestyle](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2678/living-expenses-in-abu-dhabi-for-a-moderate-lifestyle)

Comment: Yes its for Abu Dhabi :)

Comment: The costs are likely to be very similar between the two big city emirates